# How to remove extra information from URL OpenStream scanning?

Tags: java, arraylist, binary

I've created a program that takes last names from the US Census Date ([link here](http://www.census.gov/genealogy/www/data/1990surnames/dist.all.last)) and uses a binary search to find the user's last name. To be clear, I have **no problems** with this part of the code. Where I'm running into trouble is trying to remove the extra information. When I run the code, it returns the entire line. For example:

```
ROBINSON       0.233  8.372     20
```

when all I want is:

```
ROBINSON
```

How do I go about fixing this issue? My code is below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Collections;
public class NameGuesser
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, MalformedURLException
{
    ArrayList<String> lastNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    URL url = new URL("http://www.census.gov/genealogy/www/data/1990surnames/dist.all.last");        
    Scanner in = new Scanner(url.openStream());
    while (in.hasNextLine())
    {
        lastNames.add(in.nextLine());
    }
    Collections.sort(lastNames);
    int low = 0;
    int high = lastNames.size();
    int loop = 0;
    int mid = 7;
    while(loop==0)
    {
        String t1 = lastNames.get(mid);
        mid = (low+high)/2;
        System.out.println("This program tries to guess your last name, but you have to give some hints.");
        System.out.println("Does your name come before " + lastNames.get(mid) + " in the dictionary? (Y/N)");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer = input.nextLine();
        String t2 = lastNames.get(mid);
        if(t1.equals(t2))
        {
            System.out.println("Your name is " + t2);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
            high = mid;
        }
        if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
        {
            low = mid;
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This bit right here:

```
while (in.hasNextLine())
{
    lastNames.add(in.nextLine());
}
```

You're reading the entire line in and adding it to lastNames.  The data is tab-delimited, so to get rid of the extra fields, you should do this *before* you put it into lastNames:

```
while (in.hasNextLine())
{
    String lastNameLine = in.nextLine();
    String [] parts = lastNameLine.split("\\t");  // Split by tabs.
    if(parts == null || parts.length < 0) { /* uh-oh... error condition */ }
    String lastName = parts[0];
    lastNames.add(lastName);
}
```

Comment: I copied your entire code in my program, and it still came out as "ROBINSON       0.233  8.372     20".

Comment: I just edited -- you need a double backslash on \\t in the regex of split.  Also, add code to print out the individual pieces

Comment: By pieces, do you mean the individual letters?

Comment: No, I mean the parts[] array in the code I provided.